# flutter-autocomplete-textfield is not suggesting when a space is used

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using [autocomplete_textfield](https://pub.dev/packages/autocomplete_textfield) and it works great until I add a space between 2 words ,, it stop suggestion anything .. here is my code :

```dart
AutoCompleteTextField<String>(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              hintText: S.of(context).starting_location_hint),
                          itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion
                              .toLowerCase()
                              .contains(input.toLowerCase()),
                          suggestions: suggestions,
                          itemSorter: (String a, String b) {
                            return a.compareTo(b);
                          },
                          itemSubmitted: (String data) async {
                            cardKey.currentState.toggleCard();
                            fromPicked = true;
                            fromLocationName = data;
                            await movingCameraToLocation(
                                double.parse(
                                    allStations[suggestions.indexOf(data)]
                                        .stationLatitude),
                                double.parse(
                                    allStations[suggestions.indexOf(data)]
                                        .stationLongitude));
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          itemBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, String suggestion) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    suggestion,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          key: startKey,
                        )
```

Any help with that?

Comment: I am using same code and it's working for me. But I have a problem, I want to show autocomplete suggestion when tap on AutoCompleteTextField. When I am using Autocomplete optionsBuilder then it's working on tap also but with  AutoCompleteTextField it's not working.